# Special characters in input fields name="#my_input_name"?

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

Is it possible to send # identifier in input box name ="" ?

```
<input type="text" id="sq_d" name="#floor[100][section][2][room][3][sq_d]"   value="any value" >
```

OR

```
<input type="text" id="sq_d" name="#floormy_input_name"   value="any value" >
```

Comment: on clicking the event or window load ?

Comment: What did you tried ? What you got ?

Comment: what exactly you want??

Comment: On click event of submit button. It will be normal form POST method,

Comment: I want to access field value in $_POST['#floormy_input_name'], Just checked i am getting an error "Disallowed characters " in codeigniter while posting this form

Comment: @CodingCracker # will help me to identify whther input field pre-populated from database or it is newly added from jquery append().  When I loop this $_POST array I will add data of input names that begin with # into the database.